# YoloV8 train a model without losing other classes

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

If I train my model like this:

`results = model.train(data =r'Baggage detection.v15i.yolov8 (1)\data.yaml',epochs =10 )`

The new model I get has only the classes that are in my yaml file.
I want to train model so it only trains the defined classes and retains the knowledge from pretrained one.

SO basicly how do I update his detection on 1 class without messing up the others!

I tired using resume arugment but I says its no available and also passed weights = "previous model path".

Comment: you should at least provide the model argument to where you have stored the intermediate weights. Look at this github issue https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/802